# What is the best Clustering algorithm to use in clustering fire brigades , police, Ambulance in a given map?

Tags: cluster-analysis, robocup

I want to  divide the map to several parts and each part has it's assigned number of police forces , Ambulance, Fire fighters as dots in a map and the bigger the building the more forces I will need to be assigned to that building .. So can anybody recommend the best algorithm?. Note that Ambulance are for saving civilians, fire brigades are for putting out fires in buildings , Police is for clearing blocked roads only

Comment: Actually I think I understand and it is a problem approached by clustering before. I think the questioner is just looking at the distribution of services across a given city, e.g. service skews, a clustering approach is fine.

What they will genenerate is the distance between individuals/ services and create a pairwise distance matrix. This can then be solved using clustering, the problem is there are LOADs of different ones and they give different answers.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a clustering problem.

You don't want to group similar buildings or similar ambulances.

What you have is an assignment problem. You want to match providers (firefighters) and demand (buildings).

While there are of course some similarities (spatial consistency), that does not extend much beyond both being some kind of optimization problem.